# How to configure deployment of asp.net core website?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-8, webdeploy, asp.net-core-1.1

I need to publish my website with a particular web.config for each environment in order to set the environnement variable **ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT** to "Development" or "Production".

This could be achieved by sending the web.config with that content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\myProject.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </aspNetCore>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I have 2 different environments: "Development" and "Production".
I deploy my asp.net core website with webploy by using the following command :

```
msbuild myProject.csproj /p:PublishProfile=webdeploy-dev /p:DeployOnBuild=true
/p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /p:Password=...
```

There is not particular things in my webdeploy profile

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>MSDeploy</WebPublishMethod>
    <PublishProvider>AzureWebSite</PublishProvider>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>https://my.test.com</SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <MSDeployServiceURL>my.test.com</MSDeployServiceURL>
    <DeployIisAppPath>my.test.com</DeployIisAppPath>
    <SkipExtraFilesOnServer>True</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
    <MSDeployPublishMethod>RemoteAgent</MSDeployPublishMethod> <!-- MsDepSvc , WMSVC, RemoteAgent -->
    <EnableMSDeployBackup>True</EnableMSDeployBackup>
    <AuthType>NTLM</AuthType>
    <UserName>myusername</UserName>
    <EnableMSDeployAppOffline>true</EnableMSDeployAppOffline>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

How could I configure my asp.net core Project, either in the .csproj or in the webdeploy profile or anywhere else, in order to automatically send the appropriate web.config (or modify its content) to the corresponding environment ?

Comment: I'm confused. Surely you would just set the environment variable appropriately on your target machines and then never worry about it again? Are you saying the target machines can change between Development and Production?

Comment: No, the machines are differents and you're absolutely right @Cal279, the best thing I can do is to set  this environment variable directly on the machine. It's already what I did and I think it's the best practice. I'll post a answer to close that question later. Thx

Answer (score 0):

As @CalC said, I just wanted to set the environment variable on the target machines which are differents. So publishing a web.config that will override this value, that may be already set locally, is certainly dangerous and definitively not the good way to do it.

So the answer is : you should not publish the web.config to your publishing folder, but update it directly on the target machine/folder.
It's also possible to set this environment variable with other methods not covered here.